# There is equivalence in an NP-hardness proof or not?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np-hard

I want to show that some problem $P_1$ is NP-hard. I have a problem $P_2$ that is NP-complete. From an instance of $P_2$ I created in polynomial time an instance of the problem $P_1$.

My question is: Should I verify both direction ($\Leftrightarrow$) or only one direction ($\Rightarrow$)? More precisely, which one to show from these two:

- Solve $P_1\;\Leftrightarrow$ solve  $P_2$
- Solve $P_1\;\Rightarrow$ solve  $P_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to show that solving $P_1$ allows you to solve $P_2$ (and, hence, every other problem in **NP**).

$P_1$ might not be in **NP** so it's not necessarily the case that solving $P_2$ allows you to solve $P_1$.  On the other hand, if $P_1$ is in **NP**, then you already know that solving $P_2$ allows you to solve $P_1$, by definition of **NP**-completeness.

Comment: Great thanks. As I understand, if I was showing that $P_1$ is NP-complete instead of NP-hard, then I had to show the equivalence. Am I correct?

Comment: @npisinp **NP**-completeness just means that it's **NP**-hard and in **NP**. So, to show it's **NP**-complete, you just show those two things. You get equivalence with $P_2$ "for free" from the fact that they're both **NP**-complete, so you don't need to prove it separately.

Comment: I asked this question yesterday http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53495/is-the-np-hardness-proof-with-one-way-implication-correct-and-why/ and the answers say that I should prove the iff not only one way. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @1-approximation You're asking about a completely different situation. You're asking about whether it's enough to define the notion of reduction using "if" rather than "if and only if"; this question is about whether, given the standard definition of reduction, you need to establish reductions both ways between a pair of problems or just one way.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you for your time.